# Issue getting a two column div table with img to prevent overflow

Tags: css

I am trying to create a list, two items wide and however many down. Inside on div is an image, this image seems to overflow the div even when I tell it not to. An example can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aRZct/).

Can someone help me format this the way I would like it?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `overflow` property to `hidden` will prevent `div` contents from spilling over:

```
.catalogentry {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6XXrp/

*As per your comment:*

What you'll need to do then is wrap each `img` in a `div`, say of class `contain`, and specify the following in CSS:

```
.contain {
    height: /* max height you want */
    width: /* max width you want */
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Problem here is I can't see the button for the form, I can get it working by changing the http://jsfiddle.net/aRZct/1/ but there are 2 problems here still... 1.) the first row only has 1 image. 2.) if the images are different sizes there is not a constant height in the parent div see http://jsfiddle.net/aRZct/2/

Answer (score 0):

try resizing your img instead of cutting it of with overflow:hidden;

something like this:

```
.catalogentry .itemImage img {
  max-width: auto;
  max-height: 80px;
}
```

note that resizing pictures is better handled server side, to improve loading times, but that is a different story...

Comment: Good point about the server side thing, I just want to get things working correctly before I start worrying about caching and what not.